# How To Combine sub-values in Hashes of Hashes based on the Common key

Tags: perl, hash

How to combine the values in Hashes of Hashes based on the common key,

let's say:

```
%hash1 = {'abc'=>{'name'=>'xyz','address'=>'zbt'}}

%hash2 = {'abc'=>{'age'=> 25, 'gender' => 'male'}}
```

How do I combine these two hashes so that it becomes like below?

```
%hash3 = {'abc'=>{'name'=>'xyz','address'=>'zbt','age'=>25,'gender'=>'male'}}
```

Would prefer if someone could show me how to do it by using Perl Standard Module.
I am using Perl Version 5.8

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
my %hash1 = ('abc'=>{'name'=>'xyz','address'=>'zbt'});
my %hash2 = ('abc'=>{'age'=> 25, 'gender' => 'male'});

my %hash3 = map {
  $_ => {
    %{ $hash1{$_} }, %{ $hash2{$_} }
  }

} keys %hash1;
```

`$hash2{$_}` has precedence over `$hash1{$_}` when their keys clash.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are interested in using inbuilt modules you can go with Hash::Merge

In above module you can merge two hashes and specify the behaviour you want when the keys clashes between two hashes.

The option Retainment Precedence does exactly what you want and will merger the 1st level hash incase the keys clashes [click here](http://search.cpan.org/~dmuey/Hash-Merge-0.12/Merge.pm)